# Question about c pointers and * & operators

Tags: c, pointers

Let's say I have this line of code in a program:

```
int * number=0;
int mystery=&6[number];
```

Mistery is a number and I can use &5 or &4 obtaining other numbers.

But what does the "&6[]" mean?

Thanks!

Comment: It's been a long time since I've used pure C, but that `&` looks like it's taking the address of something; how can that be assigned to an `int` without casting?

Comment: @Mark compiling gives warning about that! However this example is not intended to be for right code just to understand something about pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`6[number]` is exactly equivalent to `number[6]`, so you're getting the address that's six integers away from `number`.  Since number is `0` and an `int` is 4 bytes long, the result is `24`.

Answer (score 5):

`6[variable]` is another less readable way of expressing `variable[6]`. It works because of the commutativity of the addition: `variable[6]` is the same as `*(variable + 6)`, hence `6[variable]` is the same as `*(6 + variable)`.

Answer (score 1):

I have to point out that `*(variable + 6)` is not *exactly* like `variable[6]`, this works only because the compiler knows the size of objects referred by the variable (`int` is 4 bytes in size), so what really happens is adding pointers:
`variable + 6*sizeof(int)`. It's just abstracted by the compiler.

I'm not quite sure (what's more, it may depend on the compiler), but with an array of structures this may not work because this `struct` is twice the size of the `int`:

```
struct a {
 int a;
 int b;
};

struct a arr[5];

int nmb;

struct a *res = nmb[arr]
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the nauseating `a[0] == 0[a]` "feature" of C, so you could think of it as "the address of index 6 in the array number"

Answer (score 0):

`6[number]` is the same as `number[6]`.

This is interpreted as the value the sixth element (`*(number + 6*sizeof(int))`) and since `number` is zero and `sizeof(int)` is usually `4`, then its the value at address `24`.

The `&` then gets the address of the value at address `24`, thus `mystery` is equal to `24`.

[EDIT] An `int` is typically 4 bytes long, so the correct value is `24`.

Comment: His code won't compile in this state, as `int mystery = &6[number]` attempts to bind an `int *` to an `int`. `&number[6]` is platform dependent as it is still pointer addresses - on an x86 machine, it would be 0x18. On x64, it would be 0x30 since it is started at 0.